# Installing a modified gem? ( install gem from custom github/branch globally)

Tags: ruby, rubygems, installation

I'm new to Ruby and have searched for and tried several Gems that read .doc & .docx files. [Yomu](https://github.com/Erol/yomu)
seems the best but it's super slow. This it seems is due to server mode. I've come across a [modification](https://github.com/Erol/yomu/issues/18) for this. I just can't seem to figure out how to install this [modified Yomu Gem](https://github.com/jeremybmerrill/yomu/tree/feature/servermode) over the original on my system.

Answer (score 3):

You can set a `git` and `branch` in your Gemfile for this gem (see [documentation](http://bundler.io/gemfile.html))

```
# Gemfile
gem 'yomu', :git => 'https://github.com/jeremybmerrill/yomu.git', :branch => 'feature/servermode'
```

Comment: Tried it but get an error
    `$ gem 'yomu', :git => 'https://github.com/jeremybmerrill/yomu.git' :branch => 'feature/servermode'
  -bash: https://github.com/jeremybmerrill/yomu.git: No such file or directory`

Comment: You should add this line to Gemfile and run `bundle install`

Comment: oh, I think I catch your global problem: your are trying to install gem globally to system. I would like to say that if you have ruby project you should use bundler and setup gems through Gemfile

Comment: Yes, I would like to set it up globally. As I said I'm new to Ruby so I haven't started using bundle yet but I will.

Comment: be honestly I don't know the way how to install gem from custom github/branch globally, through command `gem install ...` :(